# Suggest some more optimised solution for this rand generator

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I have a function 'generateRan' that generates random numbers. This function can not be changed.

```
int generateRan() {
    Random num = new Random();
    return (1 + num.nextInt(100));
}
```

I have to write code that will:

1. Print numbers 1-20 randomly.
2. Print numbers 1-200 randomly.

Each number should be printed only once.

The function can be used any number of times. But it is a bit heavy so I want to make the code more optimized.

Here is what I've coded:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        Test t = new Test();
        iniList(list, 20);

        for (Integer i = ((t.generateRan()) % 20); list.size() > 0; i = 1+((t
                .generateRan()) % 20)) {
            if (list.contains(i.toString())) {
                list.remove(i.toString());
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("********");

        iniList(list, 200);


        for (Integer i = ((t.generateRan()%2)*100 + t.generateRan()) ; list.size() > 0; i = ((t.generateRan()%2)*100 + t.generateRan())) {
            if (list.contains(i.toString())) {
                list.remove(i.toString());
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void iniList(List list, int i) {
        for (Integer k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
            list.add(k.toString());
        }
    }

    int generateRan() {
        Random num = new Random();
        return (1 + num.nextInt(100));
    }

}
```

**Currently the code for 1-200 is incorrect.**

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't create a `new Random()` each time the function is called. That is almost *guaranteed* to give you non-random results.

Comment: Yes, i know... but it is a compulsion, can't change this...Any other flaws u saw?

Comment: once check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator one of the most known Algo to generate Random Number

Comment: @user1433826: Perhaps you are mentally modeling your RNG as a service, with the constructor creating an interface to that service.  Instead, you should mentally model it as a state machine.  The constructor is something like `internalstate = somefunction1(currentTime);` and each call to `generateNumber` being `returnvalue = generator(internalstate); internalstate = somefunction2(internalstate);`.  Secure random number generators usually use `somefunction2(entropy)`, in which case creating new instances of Random is potentially inefficient but not necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Each numbers should print only once

Then all you need to to is create a `List<Integer>` of the entire range, then call [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

```
private static void displayNumbers(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = minInclusive; i <= maxInclusive; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int value : list) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Personally I'd *normally* use parameters of `minInclusive, maxExclusive` or `minInclusive, count`, but it looks like it may be more readable this way for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to use your generateRan() function, otherwise use Collections.shuffle as indicated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    initList(list, 200);

    while (list.size() > 0) {
        int index = generateRan() % list.size();
        System.out.println(list.remove(index));
    }
}

public static void initList(List<Integer> s, int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i ++)
        s.add(i);
}

public static int generateRan() {
    Random num = new Random();
    return (1 + num.nextInt(100));
}
```

You add all the ints you want to print to your list, then only use random to choose which one of these to print. Your function is called n times.

Comment: Tricky but nice approach +1 ;)

Comment: This won't work for the 1-200 case, or at least it won't be totally random.  For instance, the numbers 101-200 can't be the first one picked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using a Set rather than a List, for it's faster in searching for duplicates

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20;) {
    Integer r = generateRan();
    if(set.add(r)) {
        System.out.println(r);
        ++i;
    }
}
```